# Right way to detect cpu architecture?

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit, cpu-architecture

I'm attempting to detect the right cpu architecture for installing either a x86 msi or x64 msi file.

If I'm right, for the msi I need the os cpu architecture

I'm not totally sure if my way is right because I can't test it. 
What do you think?

```
private static string GetOSArchitecture()
    {
        string arch = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE");
        string archWOW = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432");
        if(archWOW != null && archWOW != "" && archWOW.Contains("64"))
            return "x64";
        if(arch.Contains("86"))
            return "x86";
        if (arch.Contains("64"))
            return "x64";
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Are you really going to ship an installer without testing it first?  That's courageous.

Comment: I can test it but just on one x64 machine and one x32 machine not on every cpu type...that's the problem

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Answer (score 3):

You could P/Invoke to [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetNativeSystemInfo), which will give the CPU architecture of the OS, even from within a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: And that's what this gives you.

Comment: A 32-bit Windows system can be installed on a 64-bit CPU.  Both MSDN and your answer "the actual CPU architecture" tell me that GetNativeSystemInfo reports x64, but Kai needs to be told x86 in this case.

Comment: Tweaked answer again.  On an x64-capable CPU running 32-bit OS, this function will return that the system has an x86 system.

Comment: Next you need to tweak MSDN :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [right](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/01/364563.aspx) way is to call [IsWow64Process](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.iswow64process). This API "Requires Windows XP SP2, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003 SP1 or Windows Server 2008" though. [This method](http://blogs.msdn.com/kstanton/archive/2004/04/20/116923.aspx) is even easier.

Comment: That won't tell you what the CPU arch is, only what the process itself is running as.

Comment: Do you need the OS architecture or the actual CPU architecture?

Comment: I need that architecture which is important for running the right msi. the code is part of an updater that downloads the msi and executes it.

Comment: ...as you might know there's no msi that runs on 32bit and 64bit cpus. due to that I need to choose the right one which i'm providing on the server.

Comment: @stuart: the intptr size method seems to be simple but will fail on WinNT.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, try executing a 64bit application.  If it fails you're on a 32bit platform.

Edited to add, based on what you're trying to do, if you make sure your msi runner application is a 32bit app then use Stuart's method.