# In C#, how can I know programmatically if the Operating system is x64 or x86

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit

In C#, how can I know programmatically if the Operating system is x64 or x86

I found this API method on the internet, but it doesn't work

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool IsWow64Process(System.IntPtr hProcess, out bool lpSystemInfo);

public static bool IsWow64Process1
{
   get
   {
       bool retVal = false;
       IsWow64Process(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out retVal);
       return retVal;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error it returns? could you post the return value of the IsWow64Process API? Also, is your .NET DLL compiled as AnyCPU?

Comment: also, try a search - bing returns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net as a result.

Comment: @obelix: There's no error, but my OS version is 64 and it returns false

Comment: Homam, if you compiled for AnyCPU, then your process may well be a native 64bit process and not under WoW64. That function may well be false validly on a 64bit OS. You've only checked whether your process is being emulated- it may be native.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right way to detect cpu architecture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017409/right-way-to-detect-cpu-architecture)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 you can use the new [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) property.

**And this is how it's impemented**

```
public static bool Is64BitOperatingSystem
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    get
    {
        bool flag;
        return ((Win32Native.DoesWin32MethodExist("kernel32.dll", "IsWow64Process") && Win32Native.IsWow64Process(Win32Native.GetCurrentProcess(), out flag)) && flag);
    }
}
```

Use reflector or similar to see exactly how it works.

Comment: Yeah, they screwed that up pretty badly.

Answer (score 2):

`bool x86 = IntPtr.Size == 4;`

Comment: this might not be correct - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net

Comment: This will show you whether you're running on 32bit  **or** you're running under WOW64 on 64bit.  It won't give you the actual *platform*, but will tell you the current runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you build against AnyCPU, and you run on a 64-bit system, it will run on the 64-bit version of the framework.  On a 32-bit system, it will run on the 32-bit version of the framework.  You can use this to its advantage by simply checking the `IntPtr.Size` property.  If the `Size` = 4, you are running on 32-bit, `Size` = 8, you are running on 64-bit.

Comment: This has gotten more complicated with .NET 4.5. The default is now "Any CPU (32-bit preferred)". See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment_members.aspx

I think you are looking for System.Environment.OSVersion

Comment: That doesn’t seem to answer the question whether it’s 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: the Environment.Is64BitProcess Property is supported only in .Net 4.0,
and I'm using 3.5

Answer (score 0):

The following is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194157/c-how-to-get-program-files-x86-on-vista-x64/194223#194223), so don't upvote me for it :)

```
if (8 == IntPtr.Size
    || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))
{
    // x64
}
else
{
    // x86
}
```