# How to know if my current operating system is Windows Vista in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know if my current os version is of type Windows Vista (could be 32bit or 64bit).
IS there a way to programmatically determine that? I just need to know if its Vista.
Thanks!

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483590/in-c-how-can-i-know-programmatically-if-the-operating-system-is-x64-or-x86

Comment: @Bridge That's actually whether it's 64bit - though this is easier for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx

Comment: @ReedCopsey I saw your answer first, but as I re-read the question I interpretted it as he wanted to know if it was 32bit/64bit version as well. I didn't label the link as a "potential duplicate" question for exactly that reason :-) (and that link you've posted here is already mentioned in the question I linked)

Comment: @Bridge I mentioned because the accepted answer there is actually not correct - it shows whehter it's *running* x86, not whether the OS is 32bit...

Comment: @ReedCopsey The second answer there is correct - lets hope OP is using .NET 4 then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check [Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) to get the [OperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.aspx) information.

```
var version = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
bool isVista =  version.Major == 6 && version.Minor == 0;
```

Comment: This question has an answer with a grid that might be useful for detecting other versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819934/detect-windows-7-in-net

Comment: This can also return true for Windows Server 2008. Mentioning it in the question might help. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx